# How to Go back automatically to the MainActivity when the user grant write setting permission?

Tags: android, permissions

I have a ringtone app ,and I need the write setting permission to change the phone ringtone and notification ... , when the user grant the permission I want to go back automatically to the app , is ther any solution ??

here is my code for requesting write setting permission :

```
public void settingPermission() {

        if (!Settings.System.canWrite(activity)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + activity.getPackageName()));
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 200);

            if (Settings.System.canWrite(activity)) {
                Intent in = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(in);
            }//this is what I tried so far but not working

        }

}
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Its easier to help you if you show some of your code where you need the assistance.

Comment: Not sure, you could try with `startActivityForResult(intentObject, YOUR_RESULT_CODE)`

Comment: @ReazMurshed I edited my post ,I tried start an activity when the user gran the permission but not working

Comment: @Shashanth didn't work :/

Comment: @Zoe I didn't now that , Im new here ,do you have any suggestions for this issue or you are just searching for post's wrong tags ??

Answer (score -1):

In the callback onPermissionGranted you can add code to launch your MainActivity i.e.

```
PermissionManager permissionManager = PermissionManager.getInstance(this);
         permissionManager.checkPermissions(singleton(Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT), new PermissionManager.PermissionRequestListener() {
             @Override
             public void onPermissionGranted() {
                 startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

             }

             @Override
             public void onPermissionDenied() {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Permissions Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });
```

Make sure your activity has the SINGLE_INSTANCE flag in the manifest if you want to avoid creating a duplicate MainActivity

Comment: thanks for your responce , where can I specify the permission that I want to test if it is granted or not ??